# Error when creating ExpandableList

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

When following this [tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/expandablelistview/android-expandablelistview-example/)

I am getting a couple of errors that I am not sure how to resolve.  In the tutorial, it extends `ExpandableListActivity` but I am unable to do that since I am using a `Fragment` so I have to extend it instead.

```
expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);
```

I am also getting an error from:

```
 adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater).getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
```

The error is `LayoutInflater cannot be resolved to a variable`

If I set a new listener on expandableList I am not sure if that will work because the listener and its methods are already in the `MyExpandableAdapter`.

Anyway, I am kind of lost here and if anyone could help me figure this out, that would be great!

Thanks to anyone looking at this!

```
 public class MuscleGroupFragment extends Fragment   {

    private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ExpandableListView expandableList;

    public MuscleGroupFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_muscle_group, container, false);

        expandableList = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandableList.setClickable(true);

        setGroupParents();
        setChildData();

        MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems);
        adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater).getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);  //Getting an error on LayoutInflater

       expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
       expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);  //Issue is this line



        return rootView;    
 }
```

Here is the adapter class

```
 public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;

public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern) {
      this.parentItems = parents;
      this.childtems = childern;
}

public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
       this.inflater = inflater;
       this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);

    TextView textView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.muscle_group_parent, null);
        }

        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String message = child.get(childPosition);
                Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.muscle_group_children, null);
    }

    //((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
    //((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

   return convertView;

}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: `adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);` note, that the dot was removed from before `getSystemService…`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, issue is on this line:

```
expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);  //Issue is this line
```

Here basically you are setting OnChildClickListener of expandable list view to "this" ie. MuscleGroupFragment class object, but this class is not implementing the OnChildClickListener interface. To resolve this issue you will have to implement this isnterface and give a implementation of the methods of this interface:

```
ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener
```

In sample example that you are refering, is using ExpandableListActivity, hence it has implemented it internally. But as you are extending Fragment class, you will have to implement OnChildClickListener.

Hope this helps you.